# Is there a way in Symfony2 to get routes for certain template name, to get templates names related to given route

Tags: php, symfony, templates, routes

Is there a way in Symfony 2:

1. To get routes for certain template name, or
2. To get templates names related to given route?

(1) For example, I have the template `symfony2blog\src\Blog\AdminBundle\Resources\views\layout.html.twig`. I would like to know in which routes it is included?

(2) For example, i have the route `blog_admin_author_show`. I would like to know templates names where this routes is included as href.

Thank you.

Comment: {{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') }}

Comment: Please add any attempts you have made to try solve your problem.

Comment: I did not made an attempt. How i can make an attempt if i can not find any function to make this? I ask if there is some simple function/command to make this? I found only php app/console router:debug, which outputs routes and related paths.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to list template for the route,
but, at least, there is a way to get listed controller name and action for the given route name/url .
You have to install the   "sed/route-exporter-bundle" : "dev-master"

```
php app/console sed:router:export --format <yaml/xml/php> --output <destination-dir>
```

will generate routing.yml file, which contains your route names and corresponding controller and action. When you can navigate to the controller action and find the template.

I was experimenting, and my application become overcrowded with annotated controllers, some of them being copies of another with duplicate route names, etc.. Thus this tool helped to put everything to single file.